# Method cannot be marked @objc because the type of the parameter 3 cannot be represented in Objective-C

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2, xcode10.1

How can I fix this? anyone can help me? thanks!

I'm using Xcode 10.1, swift 4.2

```swift
@objc func searchVenues(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D,radius: Float = 10000.0, completion: @escaping (Result<[XPVenue],Error>) -> Void) {
   // ...
}
```

The method cannot be marked `@objc` because the type of the parameter 3 cannot be represented in Objective-C

Comment: Mark the `Result` type as `@objc` as well..

Comment: Refactor your code so you don’t have to mark it as @objc maybe?

Comment: Do you really need `@objc`?

Comment: @OOPer i think so, if i don't use `@objc` , i got `no visible @interface for "xxx" declares the selector xxx`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson i think so, if i don't use `@objc` , i got "`no visible @interface for "xxx" declares the selector xxx`"

Comment: @PGDev how? can you tell me more in detail? thanks!

Comment: Do you want to call the method through selector? Or you want to use the method from Objective-C code?

Comment: Add the code for declaration of `Result` as well.

Comment: And what if you write a wrapper method without the completion handler and mark that as @objc (that’s what I meant by refactor) and use that as your selector?

Comment: @OOPer i write this method in swfit as you can see, but i want to use it in Objectice-C

Comment: The type `Result` is not available in Objective-C. You need to re-design your method if you want to use it in ObjC.

Comment: @OOPer i guess so.  thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

See the following code, Use the selector method this way `#selector(searchVenues(_:radius:completion:))`,

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(searchVenues(_:radius:completion:)), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func searchVenues(_ coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D,radius: Float = 10000.0, completion: @escaping (Result<[XPVenue],Error>) -> Void) {
   // ...
}
```